# php - set values in array from another with a condition

Tags: php, arrays, set

I have these array in php:

```
[
    {
        "idespecialidad": "001",
        "especialidad": "ALBAÑIL",
        "cantidad": "3",
        "codpais": "PE"
    },
    {
        "idespecialidad": "006",
        "especialidad": "CHEF",
        "cantidad": "1",
        "codpais": "PE"
    },
    {
        "idespecialidad": "003",
        "especialidad": "ELECTRICISTA",
        "cantidad": "2",
        "codpais": "PE"
    },
    {
        "idespecialidad": "009",
        "especialidad": "PROGRAMADOR",
        "cantidad": "1",
        "codpais": "PE"
    }
]
```

And then i have the other array:

```
{
    "001": [
        {
            "idespecialidad": "001",
            "distancia": "2.3"
        },
        {
            "idespecialidad": "001",
            "distancia": "3.4"
        },
        {
            "idespecialidad": "001",
            "distancia": "10.0"
        }
    ],
    "006": [
        {
            "idespecialidad": "006",
            "distancia": "6.9"
        }
    ],
    "003": [
        {
            "idespecialidad": "003",
            "distancia": "8.3"
        },
        {
            "idespecialidad": "003",
            "distancia": "7.5"
        }
    ],
    "009": [
        {
            "idespecialidad": "009",
            "distancia": "7.3"
        }
    ]
}
```

What i need to do is **get** the `distancia` value (specifying: the min value) and set into the first array as a new **key** depending if it has the same `idespecialidad`.

Like this (harcoded):

```
[
    {
        "idespecialidad": "001",
        "especialidad": "ALBAÑIL",
        "cantidad": "3",
        "codpais": "PE",
        "distancia": "2.3"
    },
    {
        "idespecialidad": "006",
        "especialidad": "CHEF",
        "cantidad": "1",
        "codpais": "PE",
        "distancia": "6.9"
    },
    {
        "idespecialidad": "003",
        "especialidad": "ELECTRICISTA",
        "cantidad": "2",
        "codpais": "PE",
        "distancia": "7.5"
    },
    {
        "idespecialidad": "009",
        "especialidad": "PROGRAMADOR",
        "cantidad": "1",
        "codpais": "PE",
        "distancia": "7.3"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $arr1 be your first array and $arr2 be your second

```
<?php

foreach ($arr1 as $i => $x) {
    $k = $x['idespecialidad'];
    $min = findmin($arr2, $k);
    $arr1[$i]['distancia'] = $min;
}

function findmin($data, $k)
{
    $min = $data[$k][0]['distancia'];
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($data[$k]); $i++) {
         if ($data[$k][$i]['distancia'] < $min) {
             $min = $data[$k][$i]['distancia'];
         }
    }
    return $min;
}
```